# import javascripts files to include ejs files

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm new to `EJS` and I need to import `javascript` files to included ejs files.
Previously I used jquery like following.

```
 $("#topnav").load("topnav", function () {
                $.when(
                        $.getScript( "javascripts/jquery.min.js" ),
                        $.getScript( "javascripts/custom.js" ),
                        $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
                            $( deferred.resolve );
                        }));
            });
```

Now I need to perform the same functionality with ejs. In my index.ejs file I have included topnav.ejs

```
<%- include topnav.ejs%>
```

how can I do with ejs?